# django admin view keep showing "(classname)item object(xxxxxxxxx)" for foreignkey

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, mariadb

im setting up django model and registering them on admin.py, it show nice before i register admin.ModelAdmin and use list display.... it keep showing (item object) with foreignkey column

this is my admin.py

```
class InventoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_per_page = settings.LIST_PER_PAGE
list_display = ('vchidemployee','vchserialnumber','dtedate','vchdocnum')

admin.site.register(Inventory,InventoryAdmin)
```

this is my models.py

```
class Inventoryitem(models.Model):
vchserialnumber = models.CharField(db_column='vchSerialNumber', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
vchserialnexsoft = models.CharField(db_column='vchSerialNexsoft', max_length=50, blank=True,)  # Field name made lowercase.
vchidcategory = models.ForeignKey(Itemcategory, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vchIdCategory')  # Field name made lowercase.
vchname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
intqty = models.IntegerField(db_column='intQty', default=1)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'tblInventoryItem'

class Inventory(models.Model):
vchdocnum = models.CharField(db_column='vchDocNum', primary_key=True, max_length=50,verbose_name='document number', default=increment_inventory_number)  # Field name made lowercase.
vchserialnumber = models.ForeignKey(Inventoryitem, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vchSerialNumber', verbose_name='serial number')  # Field name made lowercase.
vchidemployee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vchIdEmployee', verbose_name='employee')  # Field name made lowercase.
dtedate = models.DateField(db_column='dteDate', verbose_name='date', default=datetime.date.today)  # Field name made lowercase.
def __str__(self):
    return ("%s , %s , %s , %s" % (self.vchidemployee.vchname, self.vchserialnumber.vchname, self.dtedate, self.vchdocnum))

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'tblInventory'
```

[admin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnneK.png)

so how to change admin view instead of showing "item object(serialnumber)" to show just "serialnumber"

Comment: And the Question is???

Comment: how to change item object in admin view to show just serial number instead item object(serialnumber) like in the pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, it was mistake in my models.py